# Dynamically added UITableViewDelegate method does not respond to user interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I currently develop an iOS library which tracks user's interaction such as button tap, text editing and so on.

For tracking a table view's row selection, I use method swizzling to wrap tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: delegate method.

When tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: delegate method is defined in an application that use the library, it works well.

However, when tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: delegate method is not defined, I add it dynamically to the delegate instance but tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: delegate method is not called by a table view.

```
// Add an original tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: if not exists.
if ( ! [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)] )
{
    BOOL result = class_addMethod( [delegate class], @selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:), (IMP)tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPathIMP, types );
    if ( ! result )
        return;
}
```

When I call the added method manually, it responds.

Any ideas?

Comment: Because your delegate doesn't know about didSelect method in it, as this comes from UITableViewDelegate, if you declare this in interface of your delegate it will get to know.

Comment: I presume you are still setting the delegate, even though you are not implementing any of the delegate methods?

Comment: Since I develop a library, I can not control the library user's delegate interface directly.

Comment: I'm not sure how `class_addMethod` works with the ObjC-runtime magic. I suppose that `UITableView` does check `respondsToSelector:` before calling `UITableViewDelegate` methods as they're marked as `@optional`. I wonder if the delegate class will return `YES` for `respondsToSelector:` when a method for this selector was added by `class_addMethod`, maybe this is the reason?

Comment: @MichałCiuba I've checked now if the delegate class will return `YES` for `respondToSelector:` after it is added, and it returned `YES`. Hmm...